# (vite + Vue3) defineComponent not working on production, but works well on dev

Tags: vuejs3, vite, definecomponent

I want to use simple `defineComponent` but failed in production.

```
<script setup>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

const TestMyComponent = defineComponent({
    template: `<span>Why this not shown in production? But works well in dev</span>`,
});
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <TestMyComponent />
    </div>
</template>
```

if I run `npm run build`, it just shows blank page without any errors...

but works well if I use `npm run dev`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed the issue by adding an alias for "vue" in vite.config.ts:

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: fileURLToPath(new URL("./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js", import.meta.url)),
        },
    },
});
```

The answer is based on discussion in this link below:
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/14546#discussioncomment-7397432